# MongoDB scaling

Tags: mongodb

How much a MongoDB can scale? I heard a talk about 32bit system have 2-4GB of space available or something like that? Can it save 32GB of data in a single Mongo database in a computer and support querying that 32GB of data from that database using a regular query?

How powerful is MongoDB anyway in terms of size? And when/if the sharding comes into play. I'm looking for a gigantic database as long as the disk permits using MongoDB? It would be funny if MongoDB supports 4GB per database. I'm looking towards 200GB of storage in 5 collections in 1 mongo database in 1 computer running Mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that a single instance of MongoDB on a 32-bit system supports up to 2Gb of data. This is due to the storage engine being directly built on top of memory mapped files which have a maximum addressable space of 2Gb.

That said, I'd say very few, if any, companies will actually run a production database on 32-bit hardware so it's hardly ever an issue. On 64-bit builds the theoretical maximum storage is 2^63, but that's obviously well beyond the size of any real world dataset.

So, on a single 64-bit system you can very easily run 200Gb of data. Whether or not you want to on a production environment is another question. If you only run a single instance there's no real fail-over available. With journaling enabled and safe writes (w >= 1) you should be relatively fine though.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this document about sharding and scaling limits:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Limits

> Scale Limits
>
> Goal is support of systems of up to 1,000 shards.  Testing so far has
>   been limited to clusters with a modest number of shards (e.g., 100).